# sql server how to obtain this result set

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure as below:

Table:

```
Parent    branchname  branchlevel  level**

tree        a       1.1     1    
tree        b       1.2     1    
tree        c       1.3     1    
tree        d       1.4     1    
tree        e       1.10    1    
b           f       1.1     2    
b           g       1.2     2    
b           h       1.3     2
```

I need a result set as given below:

```
tree    1    
a       1.1    
e       1.10    
b       1.2    
f       1.2.1    
g       1.2.2    
h       1.2.3    
c       1.3    
d       1.4
```

My SQL so far:

```
select * 
from ((select distinct parent,'1' as branchlevel 
       from tree 
       where parent not in(select branchname from tree)) 
union all (select branchname,branchlevel 
           from tree 
           where (cast(level as int))<(select max(CAST(level as int)) from tree)) 
union all (select b.branchname,(SUBSTRING(b.branchlevel,1,2)+b.level+'.'+SUBSTRING(b.branchlevel,3‌​,2))branchlevel 
           from tree a 
           inner join tree b on a.branchname=b.parent 
           where (cast(a.level as int))<(select max(CAST(level as int)) from tree)))a 
order by branchlevel
```

Comment: Post here the query you tried so far.,

Comment: select * from

((select distinct parent,'1' as branchlevel from tree where parent not in(select branchname from tree))
union all
(select branchname,branchlevel from tree where (cast(level as int))<(select max(CAST(level as int)) from tree))
union all
(select b.branchname,(SUBSTRING(b.branchlevel,1,2)+b.level+'.'+SUBSTRING(b.branchlevel,3,2))branchlevel 
from tree a inner join tree b on a.branchname=b.parent 
where (cast(a.level as int))<(select max(CAST(level as int)) from tree)))a
order by branchlevel

Comment: You need to provide some additional information concerning the logic behind the required result set. E.g. why does node 'e' precede node 'b' , whereas node 'c' succeeds node 'b'?

Comment: sorry e should be the last becos it is 1.10...but wen i tried order by it was taken as 1.1.....so its e at the last. logic is first the parent and its child nodes should be displayed so tree a b f g h ...

Comment: Please edit your OP to reflect the comment you made. How many levels does your tree structure have?

Comment: only 2 levels op is tree a b f g h c d e

Comment: Is ordering of absolute importance? To you need your result set ordered as in the sample output provided in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the desired output:

```
;WITH TreeRoot AS
( 
   SELECT rootName = (SELECT TOP 1 Parent 
                      FROM #Tree
                      WHERE Parent NOT IN (SELECT branchname FROM #Tree))
),                     
TreeLevels AS (
   -- Recursive CTE Anchor member is simply: (tree, NULL, 0, 1)
   SELECT (SELECT rootName FROM TreeRoot) AS NodeName, 
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ParentName, 
          0 AS level,
          CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(10)) AS branchlevel

   UNION ALL

   SELECT branchname AS NodeName, 
          t.Parent AS ParentName, 
          tl.level + 1 AS level, 
          CAST(CONCAT(tl.branchlevel, 
               '.', 
               SUBSTRING(t.branchlevel, CHARINDEX('.', t.branchlevel)+1, LEN(t.branchlevel) - CHARINDEX('.', t.branchlevel))) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS branchlevel
   FROM #Tree AS t
   INNER JOIN TreeLevels AS tl ON t.Parent = tl.NodeName
)
SELECT NodeName, branchlevel
FROM TreeLevels
ORDER BY branchlevel
```

The `SUBSTRING` function is used to obtain the last number out of the branchlevel field, i.e. to get '2' out of '1.2'. `CONCAT` is used to recursively add this number to any previously attained branchlevel numbers.

This query will work even if branching levels are more than 2. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2b76/2)